# Is there a safe way to use SqlBulkCopy across multiple threads

Tags: sql-server, thread-safety, sqlbulkcopy

We've introduced SqlBulkCopy on a batch job that executes across multiple threads but are now getting intermittent deadlocks. We're not using the table lock option. The table being inserted has a clustered index.

Each thread is inserting for a unique PortfolioSnapshotId (with a batch of AssetIds)

Is there any way we can safely use SqlBulkCopy in this scenario?

XML below:

```
<event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2017-12-06T02:38:31.382Z">
  <data name="xml_report">
    <type name="xml" package="package0" />
    <value>
      <deadlock>
        <victim-list>
          <victimProcess id="process248e1c96108" />
        </victim-list>
        <process-list>
          <process id="process248e1c96108" taskpriority="0" logused="63904" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:289932632 " waittime="4523" ownerId="2409980792" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.657" XDES="0x2453d39ce58" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="14" kpid="24604" status="suspended" spid="151" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.657" lastbatchcompleted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.657" lastattention="2017-12-06T02:38:23.760" clientapp="XXXX" hostname="XXXX" hostpid="137000" loginname="XXXX" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2409980792" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="1206" sqlhandle="0x020000000f2bea1e535f1cbf04ef8318984df8965399be020000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
insert bulk TableName ([AssetId] NVarChar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [ParentAssetId] NVarChar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [PortfolioSnapshotId] UniqueIdentifier, [Quantity] Decimal(28,8), [CompressedProperties] VarBinary(max)) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)   </inputbuf>
          </process>
          <process id="process248e1c8cca8" taskpriority="0" logused="67244" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:289933280 " waittime="4523" ownerId="2409980337" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.220" XDES="0x25e82396e58" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="2" kpid="33292" status="suspended" spid="158" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.220" lastbatchcompleted="2017-12-06T02:38:26.220" lastattention="2017-12-06T02:38:24.507" clientapp="XXXX" hostname="XXXX" hostpid="137000" loginname="XXXX" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2409980337" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
              <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="1206" sqlhandle="0x020000000f2bea1e535f1cbf04ef8318984df8965399be020000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
insert bulk TableName ([AssetId] NVarChar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [ParentAssetId] NVarChar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [PortfolioSnapshotId] UniqueIdentifier, [Quantity] Decimal(28,8), [CompressedProperties] VarBinary(max)) with (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)   </inputbuf>
          </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
          <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="289932632" dbid="14" subresource="FULL" objectname="XXXX.dbo.TableName" id="lock247f3004d00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594048872448">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process248e1c8cca8" mode="X" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process248e1c96108" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
          </pagelock>
          <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="289933280" dbid="14" subresource="FULL" objectname="XXXX.dbo.TableName" id="lock247f4f97c80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045661184">
            <owner-list>
              <owner id="process248e1c96108" mode="X" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
              <waiter id="process248e1c8cca8" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
            </waiter-list>
          </pagelock>
        </resource-list>
      </deadlock>
    </value>
  </data>
</event>
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
  [AssetId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [ParentAssetId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [PortfolioSnapshotId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [Quantity] [decimal](28, 8) NULL,
  [CompressedProperties] [varbinary](max) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [PortfolioSnapshotId] ASC,
  [AssetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TableName_PortfolioSnapshot] FOREIGN KEY([PortfolioSnapshotId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PortfolioStore_PortfolioSnapshot] ([Id])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName_PortfolioSnapshotId] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
  [PortfolioSnapshotId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [AssetId],
  [ParentAssetId],
  [Quantity],
  [Price]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Add the deadlock info (the XML, not a picture of it), along with all relevant table structure, including every index.

Comment: @RemusRusanu done :)

Answer (score 2):

The deadlock occurs because of the presence of the NC index (page lock IX->X on two different object Id from the same object name). I don't see the reason for the NC index, considering that the clustered index is on the same key and more selective. I would remove that NC index.

Comment: The NC index is there because it excludes the CompressedProperties column which is otherwise very large, and therefore less data to scan when filtering on those columns. We have considered pulling this data out into a separate table. Not sure if there are other options here? I'm not entirely clear why the index causes the deadlock itself? Can you clarify? Thanks very much!

Comment: Use [`sp_tableoption 'large value types out of row'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql)